# Function to convert single objects to an array?

Tags: java

I wanted to write a function that would take an object and convert it to an array that contains that object as a single element.  It occurred to me that I could maybe do this with generics and variable arguments to essentially do this automatically, without the need to write a function for each object type I wished to use.  Will this code work?  Are there any subtleties I need to be aware of?

```
public static <X> X[] convert_to_array(X... in_objs){
    return in_objs;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It works but it seems like:

```
 Object o = new Object();
 someMethod(new Object[] { o } );
```

is a little more straightforward then:

```
Object o = new Object();
someMethod(convert_to_array(o));
```

In cases where sometimes I want to pass a single object, but other times I want to pass an array, usually I just use an overloaded method in the API:

```
public void doSomething(Object o)
{
    doSomething(new Object[] { o } );
}

public void doSomething(Object[] array)
{
    // stuff goes here.
}
```

Varargs can be used but only if the array is the last parameter of course.

Answer (score 11):

Why not simply:

```
Object o = new Object();
Object[] array = { o }; // no method call required!
```

What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: The first line creates a new object and assigns its reference to the variable named 'o'. The second line creates an array of the Object type with a single element (the reference we created earlier) and assigns the array's reference to the variable named 'array'. Does that help? If not, let me know what questions remain.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need a that you need an array that is properly typed, you can use java.lang.reflect.Array:

```
static public Object[] createTypedArray(Object elm) {
    Object[] arr=(Object[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(elm.getClass(),1);
    arr[0]=elm;
    return arr; // this can be cast safely to an array of the type of elm
    }
```